# How to store DB payloads and send them back up via Telemetry when not directly associated?

Tags: c#, azure, telemetry

I've been trying to find a way to record all DB calls made during a HttpGet/Post.  I am already logging the last one in case an error occurs, but the problem is that now I need to record all of them.  The logging implemented currently interacts with Azure insights fine, but if I were to record all calls and send them back, I would get both unassociated data and too much data.  So I'm looking for a way to only record and send back associated calls.  I was thinking of storing all the calls in a Dictionary<int id, List<string> Payloads>.

This is how I am currently sending the last payload to azure

```
public class ODataURLInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        if (requestTelemetry != null)
        {
            requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("Last OData URL", ODataURLCapturer.URLs);
        }
        
    }
}
```

So I guess the real question is how do I store and retrieve data when calls are only barely associated.

Comment: You can create custom Appender's using Log4Net.  For example, you can make a Web API that logs to a remote database in your custom Appender.

Answer (score 0):

Azure application insights can provide dependency metric. You can [add application insights sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core#enable-application-insights-server-side-telemetry-no-visual-studio) into your application and [enable-Sql-Command-Text-Instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query) for logging sql command.

Add configuration in startup.cs to enable sql command text when using asp.net core

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // The following line enables Application Insights telemetry collection.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) => { module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true; });
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

[image]